# How can I check if a module is enabled?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, you can use [module_exists()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_exists/7) to check whether a module is enabled (as well as whether it exists).

For example,

```
if (module_exists('devel')) {
```

How can you check whether a module is enabled in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just like Clive mention....

> injecting the `module_handler`service would be preferable to using \Drupal (assuming it's an option in current context)

Here is an example of checking if a module is enabled using a service (without injecting it).

```
$moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
if ($moduleHandler->moduleExists('devel')) {
  // Code Here
}
```

Comment: `\Drupal::moduleHandler` ends up just making an equivalent call to get the "module_handler" service anyway (see the [moduleHandler doco](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AmoduleHandler/8.2.x)). The key word in Clives comment was _injecting_, i.e. passing the service to a constructor.

Comment: Even though this is not an injection, this code is probably the best you can have if running in a hook_update_nnn() function in your module's .install file, as there's no way of injecting services in a functional context.

Comment: This is exactly the same as the code shown from the other answer, which is preferable when the `Drupal` class has an helper method. If a hook is only using a service, I would not use injection; in the case the services are more than one, it's possible to write code that uses injection, via a class.

Answer (score 25):

Like this:

```
  if (\Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('devel')) {
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that injecting the `module_handler` service would be preferable to using `\Drupal` (assuming it's an option in current context)

Comment: @Clive why is that preferable?

Comment: @ryrye Because you can mock injections in tests, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/services-and-dependency-injection-in-drupal-8#s-using-dependency-injection